# Получить TextWriter из дочернего AppDomain'a

Tags: c#, .net, clr, appdomain

Можно как то из AppDomain'a перехватить поток `TextWriter`, для того что бы достать то что пишет `Console.WriteLine()` в методе из дочернего AppDomain'a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет необходимости "перехватывать" `TextWriter`, можно просто подменить писца, который будет использоваться консолью в дочернем домене. Идея в следующем: напишем небольшой класс, который будет выполняться в дочернем домене и подменять писца:

```
[Serializable]
internal class RemoteDomainConsoleTracer
    : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private TextWriter _origWriter;

    public void SetWriter(TextWriter writer)
    {
        _origWriter = Console.Out;
        Console.SetOut(writer);
    }

    public void ResetWriter()
    {
        Console.SetOut(_origWriter);
    }
}
```

Теперь необходимо создать экземпляр этого класса в дочернем домене и после того, как в консоль будет записано всё, что требуется, прочитать уже в родительском домене:

```
internal class RemoteDomainConsoleListener
{
    private RemoteDomainConsoleTracer _tracer;
    private StreamWriter _writer;
    private MemoryStream _stream;

    public RemoteDomainConsoleListener(AppDomain foreignDomain)
    {
        _tracer = (RemoteDomainConsoleTracer)foreignDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
            typeof(RemoteDomainConsoleTracer).FullName);
    }

    public void StartListen()
    {
        _stream = new MemoryStream();
        _writer = new StreamWriter(_stream);
        _tracer.SetWriter(_writer);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        _tracer.ResetWriter();
        _writer.Flush();
        _stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(_stream).ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Использовать всё это можно так:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var childDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Child domain");
        var remoteDomainConsoleListener = new RemoteDomainConsoleListener(childDomain);

        var child = (EntryPoint)childDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
            typeof(EntryPoint).FullName);

        remoteDomainConsoleListener.StartListen();
        child.Run();
        remoteDomainConsoleListener.Flush();
        AppDomain.Unload(childDomain);
    }
}
```

Хочу заметить, что внесение какого-либо специфичного кода в дочерний домен не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо! EntryPoint это имеется в виду RemoteDomainConsoleTracer?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, нет. `EntryPoint` - это точка входа в код "полезной нагрузки", то есть в тот код, который выполняется в дочерние домене и чьи записи в консоль надо перехватывать. `RemoteDomainConsoleTracer` инициализируется точно также в конструктора класса `RemoteDomainConsoleListener`.